# How to detect focus or touched on md-contact-chips in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to detect if a user has focus on md-contact-chips.

On all other controls it can easily be detected inside a form via `formName.controlName.$touched`

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pggyaw)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the md-contact-chips are not a form element or a link, and thus don't have the ability to gain / lose focus. (source: [AngularJS docs on ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)) You could bind ng-click on md-contact-chips though.

[Example CodePen which binds ng-click and receives the model value of the clicked md-contact-chips.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMMGEW)

As you can see I added a `ng-click` to the md-contact-chips element:

```
<md-contact-chips ng-click='ctrl.chipFocus(ctrl.contacts)'
```

And I added the `chipFocus` method to the AngularJS controller:

```
self.chipFocus = function(contact) {
  alert('focus gained');
  console.log(contact);
  //you could do something with contact here
};
```

Comment: That's true, so what if you change the md-contact-chip / the largest inner element of the md-contact-chip into an `a` element, and then bind ng-focus on that `a` element?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer to your question, but if you want the chips input to add on loseFocus, or tab, you can add this:

```
md-add-on-blur="true"
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/9095